# Programmatically determining programming languages based on file extensions in python

Tags: python, sorting, programming-languages, file-extension

If I have a group of random files (source code) in many different languages, is there a library or API I can pass the file extension of each file into for determining which language the file is for, so I may organize these files according to language type?
(I need to know the language I cant just sort by file extension)

Comment: You could probably implement it yourself fairly easily. And you can sort by file extension. For example, if you have `file.py`, you know it's a python file from the file extension.

Comment: well, I don't have control over my input files, otherwise, I agree that would be easy for me to deduce, I think I may have a solution with Githubs Linguist tool it's written in Ruby, but has a [python wrapper I found available on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/ghlinguist/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using [this](https://github.com/blakeembrey/language-map/blob/master/languages.json) JSON translated version of Github's Linguist YAML map, for an NPM package, and imported it and just did a dictionary lookup on a set of maps, for any who are interested this is the part of my solution that's relivant:

```
language_results = list(map(
        lambda file_args: file_args[0] if file_extension in list(map(
            lambda i: i, file_args[1].get("extensions", []))) else None, language_map.items()))
language_results = list(filter(None, language_results))
return language_results[0] if len(language_results) > 0 else None
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some module, which recognizes mime-type of this file.
You can also sort it by first line in script
(e.g. `#!/bin/python`, `#!/bin/sh`, ...), if using it.

Comment: I like this solution, and I pursued it, however, it just wasn't as extensive or had the coverage I felt I needed.